# CheckBox to limit a data validation list

Tags: vba, excel, validation, checkbox

Moving forward, slowly.......

I added a column, that with the combination of my checkboxes, gives the name of active employees.

#### Screen Shot of active list of employees

[image: Screen Shot of active list of employees]

If I use $T$6:$T$16 as my validation list, I still get 11 options in the drop down. I want the drop down to show only the 5 names that are in that list.

Comment: One suggested change to your proposed setup. Don't use checkboxes, instead create an "Active" column and put TRUE or FALSE in each cell as appropriate. This is going to be easier to maintain and refer to.

Comment: show your code for checkboxes to fill column T

Comment: =IF(Tbl_Emplys[IS ACTIVE],VLOOKUP(Tbl_Emplys[ID],Tbl_Emplys,2,FALSE),)

Comment: ^^^this is what populates column T

Answer (score 1):

No need to use VBA here, Here's a quick solution.

Use a 1 or 0 in a column next to the employees' names corresponding to whether they are active or not.

Then create a column in the sales sheet which has a vlookup for this value

```
=VLOOKUP(E4,$A$4:$B$8,2,FALSE)
```

This looks for value E4 (the name), in range of all names, second column for their active status, FALSE for an exact match.

Then use a filter:

- Highlight range of sales
- "Data" tab
- "Filter"

Then you can use the filter on the new Active column to only show the employees which are still active. See the linked image for the final outcome. The vlookup lives in column D.

**Final outcome image in Excel**

[image]

Of course if you want this in two sheets, you can split what I've done to different sheets with no extra effort other than adding sheet references to the range in the vlookup.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for your addition to my question. however I am not seeing how this will limit the choices in my drop dwon data validation list.

Comment: Because if you have the extra column (which looks up whether or not the employee is active) then you can filter by only those who are... is this not what you are looking for? You can filter by this first, then do any other validation...

Comment: Again, thank you for the reply. I did update my question by adding some screen shots of what it is I am looking for if that helps clearify what I am asking.

Comment: =IF(Tbl_Emplys[IS ACTIVE],VLOOKUP(Tbl_Emplys[ID],Tbl_Emplys,2,FALSE),), this still leaves me with 9 options in the drop down data validation list. I need it to only have the options for who ever is active